# problems using host file in coredns

Tags: coredns

I am trying to use the hosts plugin to use a hosts file in coredns.
It works if I add a hostname, but if I use more than one it does not.
I added this in my coredns.yaml

```
hosts /etc/kubernetes/example.hosts example.com {
        192.168.1.233 myserver.example.com
              fallthrough
           }
```

from a busybox I can ping myserver.example.com. Good

If I add another hostname like this

```
hosts /etc/kubernetes/example.hosts example.com {
              192.168.1.233 myserver.example.com
              192.168.2.256 myserver2.example.com
              fallthrough
           }
```

than from the busybox I can't ping neither myserver not myserver2
What am I doing wrong ?